# How to use a relative path in XDocument.Load with Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I always get the system not found exception. How can I find a xml file in a bundle of my xamarin.android application?

```
public Dictionary<string, string> TilePropertiesForTileID(short tileGid)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> propertiesDict = null;

        try
        {

            // Loading from a file, you can also load from a stream
            var xml = XDocument.Load(Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "Assets/Content/tileMap/wood_tileset.tsx"));

            // Query the data and write out a subset of contacts
            var propertiesQuery = from c in xml.Root.Descendants("tile")
                                  where (int)c.Attribute("id") == tileGid
                                  select c.Element("property").Value;


            foreach (string property in propertiesQuery)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Property: {0}", property);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw e;
        }

        return propertiesDict;
    }
```

This line:

```
var xml = XDocument.Load(Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "Assets/Content/tileMap/wood_tileset.tsx"));
```

always throws the exception. I don't know How to get access to this file.

**updated: Thanks to apineda I am now able to find the file : here is the xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tileset version="1.2" tiledversion="1.2.1" name="wood_tileset" 
    tilewidth="32" tileheight="32" tilecount="256" columns="16">
 <image source="wood_tileset.png" width="512" height="512"/>
 <tile id="68">
  <properties>
   <property name="IsTreasure" value="true"/>
  </properties>
 </tile>
</tileset>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this you don't necessarily need the Full Path of the File. Since you placed the file in the Assets directory and I hope also marked it as `AndroidAsset` in the *Build Action* all you need is to make use of the `AssetManager`.

If you are within an Activity you can open a file in the Assets like this:

`Assets.Open("fileName.ext")`

If you added subdirectories in the Assets directory you will need to include the full path (without including the word "Assets").

Using your code as sample, it should look like this:

```
using (var sReader = new StreamReader(Assets.Open("Content/titleMap/wood_tileset.tsx")))
{
    var xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(sReader);

    // Query the data and write out a subset of contacts
    var propertiesQuery = xmlDoc.Root.Descendants("tile")
                                .Where(item => (int)item.Attribute("id") == tileGid)
                                .SelectMany(a => a.Descendants("property"))
                                .Select(property => new
                                { 
                                    Name = property.Attribute("name").Value, 
                                    Value = property.Attribute("value").Value
                                })
                                .ToList();

    foreach (var property in propertiesQuery)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Property Name: {property.Name}, Value: {property.Value}");
    }
}
```

As you can see the return of the `Assets.Open` method is passed into a StreamReader. The `using` is not necessary but this will prevent leaving resources opened.

The StreamReader is then passed in to the `Load()` method of the `XDocument` and the rest is exactly as you had it.

Note: This assume you have a file structure like the following:

```
Assets    
     Content
       titleMap
          wood_titleset.tsx
```

Hope this helps.-

Comment: Where specifically? Also as noted above please make sure the file is set with the correct **Build Action** of  **AndroidAsset**.

Comment: once we start the first iteration of the foreach, it throw the null exception. I think we missed to parse the <properties> node over <property> ?

Comment: Yes, it seems you are having problem parsing the XML. What's your XML structure?

Comment: what a shame, I though I added it to my question. One moment,i will update it!

Comment: I updated my question with the xml file. I am near to the answer.. I don't figure out how to parse my xml.

Comment: @ChristopheGudlake based on your XML structure you have provided I have updated the answer to help you reading the properties. Sorry that I changed the LInQ to C# Style. Also notice that I created an anonymous type to "parse" the properties so that way you can access to Properties (Name and Value) instead of just strings. You can create a new class if you like, did this for simplicity.